# How can I configure IIS to use customerrors with option set to recreate for all extensions/MIMEs?

Tags: iis, mime-types, file-extension, custom-errors

I'm currently using customErrors, and I would like to use the recreate option, always.

This currently works for URLs such as
`mysite.com/asdf`

My custom error page loads as this URL:
`mysite.com/asdf`

---

However, this is not working for URLs such as
`mysite.com/asdf.aspx`

My custom error page loads as 
`mysite.com/mycustomerrorpage.aspx?errorpath=/asdf.aspx`

This is handled by IIS as a 302 redirect to the error page above with a status of 200 when it loads.

---

What I'm trying to accomplish: I want the user to receive an http status of 404 (or respective status code), and I want the page to recreate always (regardless of extension or lack of extension). I do not want a 302 redirect from IIS, and I do not want the custom error page to return as a 200.

I'm new to IIS - This seems like it would be a basic thing, but I'm having more troubles than I would've guessed :)

Thank you in advance for any assistance!